# Syncing a Windows Phone device with Ubuntu (or a generic Unix distro)

Tags: 7.x, synchronization

I have a Nokia Lumia 710 running Windows Phone 7.8. I used to have it synchronised with my home PC which runs Windows 7. However, this September I'm leaving to another city because of university, and I won't be able to access that PC. I'll have to rely on my laptop, that runs Ubuntu 12.10.

So, I'd like to know whether there is a software that would allow me to sync my device on Ubuntu; if possible, I'd like not to install any virtual machine.

Comment: I think WP7+ can only be accessible via Zune or MAC connector. Never heard about sync with Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just contacted support via their twitter account.

Unfortunately they said a version for Linux is currently unavailable.

Source: https://twitter.com/WinPhoneSupport/status/494647002945576961

Comment: If it's any consolation, phones running 8.x connect as an MTP device, so don't need special sync software